# Is it safe to throw an exception in C++ in a callback registered in clCreateContext()

Tags: c++, opencl

When programming OpenCL and using C++, when calling the function clCreateContext(....), I have the option of registering a callback function in the even something goes wrong. Is it safe to throw an exception in this callback?  Being that OpenCL is a C API and doesn't use exceptions, I wasn't sure if there would be any problems with this approach of error handling.

Comment: I've never used CL, but will take an educated guess and say "no".

Comment: I would check the documentation for info on the callback and how error handling is expected by the code invoking the callback.  If the invoker is expecting you to return an error code in case of problems then you should do that.  I'm not sure what benefit you would gain by throwing an exception back to someone else's code invoking your callback when its not expecting exceptions in the first place.

Comment: The interesting question would be: Where does the exception go? Since the callback is called from OpenCL, and presumably not the main thread, there is no guarantee (it is not even likely) that an exception ever gets anywhere near your handling code (considerations like module boundaries left aside). So there is not much useful stuff it could possibly do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not throw exceptions across interface/module boundaries, and this would count as one. What would probably happen is that the exception would be unhandled and your program would crash.